# What is the simplest way to do upsert with Ecto (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Doing upsert is common in my app and I want to implement the cleanest and simple way to implement upsert.

1. Should I use fragments to implement native sql upsert?
2. Any idiomatic ecto way to do upsert?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [Ecto.Repo.insert_or_update/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_or_update/2), please note that for this to work, you will have to load existing models from the database.

```
 model = %Post{id: 'existing_id', ...}
 MyRepo.insert_or_update changeset
 # => {:error, "id already exists"}
```

Example:

```
result =
  case MyRepo.get(Post, id) do
    nil  -> %Post{id: id} # Post not found, we build one
    post -> post          # Post exists, using it
  end
  |> Post.changeset(changes)
  |> MyRepo.insert_or_update

case result do
  {:ok, model}        -> # Inserted or updated with success
  {:error, changeset} -> # Something went wrong
end
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case `insert_or_update` raised an error due to the unique index constraint

What did work for me was *Postgres v9.5* upsert through [`on_conflict`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/constraints-and-upserts.html) parameter:

(considering unique column is called `user_id`)

```
changeset
|> MyRepo.insert(
    on_conflict: :replace_all,
    conflict_target: :user_id
)
```

Comment: This approach won't work on MySQL 5..7.  Just learned that :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to upsert by something other than `id`, you can swap in `get_by` for `get` like this:

```
model = %User{email: "existing_or_new_email@heisenberg.net", name: "Cat", ...}

model |> User.upsert_by(:email)
# => {:found, %User{...}} || {:ok, %User{...}}

defmodule App.User do
  alias App.{Repo, User}

  def upsert_by(%User{} = record_struct, selector) do
    case User |> Repo.get_by({selector, record_struct |> Map.get(selector)}) do
      nil -> %User{} # build new user struct
      user -> user   # pass through existing user struct
    end
    |> User.changeset(record_struct |> Map.from_struct)
    |> Repo.insert_or_update
  end
end
```

On the off chance you're looking for a flexible approach that works across models and for multiple selectors (ie country + passport number), check out my hex package [EctoConditionals](https://github.com/codeanpeace/ecto_conditionals)!

Comment: This answer doesn't necessarily work because you have to have an id to use with `insert_or_update`.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for bring that up! Though the docs appear to suggest that `insert_or_update/1` needs an id key in the struct, it doesn't seem to actually require it.

Feel free to see for yourself by running something to the effect of`%User{} |> User.changeset(%{email: "heisen@berg.com"}) |> Repo.insert_or_update`

Comment: You don't need an id for the insert, you do need one for the update. `Repo.update` always does the update based on the `id` of the record. So, if you don't have an `id` then you can't update.

Comment: In the update case, `Repo.get_by/2` would return a User struct that has a valid id. But yes, you are right that an id is necessary to update.